# inline assembly in file scope of c

Tags: c, file, scope, inline-assembly

I known the inline assembly in function scope of c.
but, I find that I can also declare an asm statement(basic assembly, not extended by gnu) in file scope.
I would like to know the function of the inline assembly in file scope of c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a feature like any other, you use it to solve a specific problem.  Scanning the linux kernel, you see this used in a number of places.  Here's one, along with an explanation of why it was done this way:

[bioscalls.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/pnp/pnpbios/bioscalls.c#L29)

Comment: could you make a detailed description of it.
when it will be executed? I write a test program, but the result is not my expected. the code :

int x asm("xyz") = 0;
asm("movl $11, %eax;");
asm("movl %eax, xyz;");
int main() {
    printf("==: x = %d \n", x);
}
would you like to tell me the reason?

Comment: Which "it?"  What the code I linked to does?  I thought the comments with the code already did a decent job of explaining what it does and why.  The file-scope asm feature?  There's not much to say, but you can look at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Basic-Asm.html

Comment: Ahh, you have edited your comment.  So, I'm not sure where to start with what is wrong with that code.  Probably the main thing is that the asm will never get called.  When the compiler/linker generate the code, they "start" by running your "main()".  There are exceptions where initializers at file scope can be run before main.  asm however doesn't fall in this category.  Which makes sense, since gcc doesn't even "know" that the asm contains executable code.  It could just be some assembler directives.  The linux link I provided defines a subroutine that is called elsewhere, not at startup.